# Test USB drives using Mac OS

Tags: usb-flash-drive, usb-storage

Edited: I use f3 (f3write, f3read, f3probe) to test USB drives in Linux. How do I test them in Mac OS? It would be useful to be able to test the USB drives on my Mac without having to put them on an older, slower Linux computer. If there is a way that requires a software addition I would prefer not to have to compile to use it.

Specifically, I'd like to test to ensure the drives have no corrupted sectors and that they have the advertised size, for instance, 64 GiB.

Comment: @dsstorefile1 - This is good. Please make this an Answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a variation of f3 named [F3X](https://github.com/insidegui/F3X) that offers a [precompiled app bundle](https://github.com/insidegui/F3X/releases/download/1.1/F3X_1.1.zip) for macOS, but the repo is archived and the most recent bundle is from 2015.

---

As an alternative, the F3 [readme](https://github.com/AltraMayor/f3/blob/master/README.rst) says package managers like HomeBrew and MacPorts can take care of the build and installation process via

```
brew install f3
```

or

```
port install f3
```

Comment: This doesn't include f3probe unfortunately